# Fourier series: two different expressions for same period of integration

Tags: fourier-series

I'm currently studying Fourier series. I'm having trouble finding the right expressions for coefficients $a_0, a_n$ and $b_n$. I have 3 sources and 3 different expressions:

My lecture notes states:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\cos(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\sin(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

[This website](https://www.thefouriertransform.com/series/coefficients.php) says:

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)dt$$

$$a_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\cos(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

$$b_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\sin(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

and [this](https://pidlaboratory.com/4-complex-fourier-series/) other shows both expressions for $a_n$ and $b_n$ as correct:

**with real part:**

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)dt$$

$$a_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\cos(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

$$b_n = \frac{2}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\sin(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

**without real part:**

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)dt$$

$$a_n = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\cos(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 f(t)\sin(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t)dt$$

It is clear that this eqs are not equivalent.

so...

1. What are the correct expressions?
2. What it refers when says "with real part" and "without real part"?

Comment: Notes in error.  First website correct.  Second website seems to break up real and imaginary parts - I have not tried to figure it out.